# Azure BotFramework Speech WebSocket Error

Tags: azure, websocket, speech-recognition, chatbot

I have an Azure Chatbot with Speech-to-Text.

```
const webSpeechPonyfillFactory = window.WebChat.createCognitiveServicesSpeechServicesPonyfillFactory({
                subscriptionKey: 'XXXXXXX',
                region: 'westeurope'
            })

            window.WebChat.renderWebChat({
                directLine: window.WebChat.createDirectLine({
                //  token: token
                    secret: 'XXXXXXXX'
                }),
                webSpeechPonyfillFactory,
                // disable timestamp
                groupTimestamp: false,

                //set language
                locale: 'en-US',

                styleOptions: {

                    hideUploadButton: true,

                    avatarSize: 0   
                }
            }, 
                document.getElementById('webchat'));
```

This is how I implement my Speech service to my Webchat.

Till yesterday evening everything worked perfectly, but when I came to my office this morning and tried it again, I get following Error:
[image]

It pops up when I click on the microphone button, and continues to pop up till I click on it again.

As I didn't change anything in my code till yesterday (when it perfectly worked) I just don't know what to do.

I don't use the latest version of webchat, I implement the 4.7.1, so a failed update can't be the problem.

-- Edit1 --

Text is working fine, just the Speech doesn't work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was no error in my code.
Was an Error by cognitve services but is fixed now.

See https://github.com/microsoft/BotFramework-WebChat/issues/2802 for further information.